# What are the good ways to monitor celery tasks?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I am facing a weird issue with celery. Sometimes celery process was running for a particular task and worker but actually, It was not performing the function it should.

I have seen the celery docs where they have mentioned munin exchange links which are broken now.

```
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#monitoring-munin

http://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/search.html?q=celery&check_keywords=yes&area=default#
```

Is there any way to monitor celery processes?

Answer (score 0):

Flower - a web based tool for monitoring and administrating Celery clusters
http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I am already using flower to check the status of the task but I want to monitor the celery processes so that if task stops then it should have the capability to restart itself. But now, I am using supervisord to do so. :)